# Java control Windows Media Player with Java

Tags: java, android, wmp

I have seen some Java servers which can control WMP with an Android device or such. But how do you make a server that controls WMP?
What do you need for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Media Player supports [UPnP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play) for server discovering and [DLNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Living_Network_Alliance) for remote controlling.

Say if you want to create a client app (Android or whatsoever using Java) to remote control Windows Media Player:

- Use UPnP to discover available WMP server on network with [zero configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_configuration_networking).
- Use DLNA to remote control available WMP server on network, for example, expose playlist, control volume and etc.

Java library implements UPnP/DLNA: [Cling](http://4thline.org/projects/cling)

Hope this make sense.